# OnItemSelectedListener not working in tab fragment

Tags: java, android

I have spinner in tab fragment, and I need OnItemSelectedListener in my code. I was looking for some examples, but they are mostly in MainActivitys. So, I couldn figure out how to work this in fragment. Please, help.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    private Button loadButton;
    private Spinner turnPointsSpinner;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task, container, false);

        loadButton = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        turnPointsSpinner = (Spinner)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        ArrayAdapter<TurnPoints> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<TurnPoints>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SingletonTurnPoints.getInstance().mTurnPoints);     
        myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);     
        turnPointsSpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        OnItemSelectedListener countrySelectedListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View container,
                    int position, long id) {

                Log.d("tag", "selected");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };

        // Setting ItemClick Handler for Spinner Widget
        turnPointsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(countrySelectedListener);

        loadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //when button Load is clicked, we start new activity for file browsing 
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BrowseFileActivity.class);
            //FragmentTask.this.startActivity(intent);
            startActivity(intent);
            Log.d("tag", String.valueOf(intent));
            }           
        });


        return myFragmentView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `OnItemClickListener` and just keep the `OnItemSelectedListener`.

Spinners use `OnItemSelectedListener` and it's more than likely that setting both is confusing everything.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: I put both implementations just to show what I was trying to do. I remove OnItemCickListener and it's working now. Thanks a lot. I also edit the code.

Comment: Now it seems that sometimes is working, sometime is not, I'm confused. I just get message in debug: "07-18 09:14:12.830: D/memalloc(4103): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5e91c000 size:17600512 offset:13832192 fd:83" but sometimes is working, and I see my debug "selected". What could be wrong?

Comment: Is it erroring? Can you post the full stack trace? What is `SingletonTurnPoints.getInstance().mTurnPoints`?

Comment: OK, I figure it out what is the problem. It starts working when I reselect tab. Spinner is also not updated with selected value, since tab is not reselected. How can I refresh tab? Or what is solution here? SingletonTurnPoints.getInstance().mTurnPoints is my global accessed ArrayList..

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. I feel I've answered why your `onItemSelectedListener` was not firing. Maybe someone else can help or alternatively I advise you to open up a new question explaining what you expect to happen, what you're trying to accomplish, and what's not working.